# Interpret Trx read view will not see statement in innodb Engine status

Tags: mysql, innodb

In mysql engine status we see like below, how can I interpret the below statement:

```
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 258501998, sees < 0 258501972
```

As an added note I can see the 258501972 is the id of an another transaction running for a long.

[

```
---TRANSACTION  258501972 ACTIVE 403 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 7, locked 7
...
...
TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 8 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
```

RECORD LOCKS space id 1791 page no 379292 n bits 120 index `PRIMARY` of table `DBNAME`.`TBLNAME` trx id 258501972 lock mode S waiting

]